# How to find and delete a specific record in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am totally newbie in Ember. I would like to find a record in `todos` array then delete it. I know I have to pass a parameter to `function` to find it first then delete it, but I had no luck. Here are related files:

**todos.hbs**:

```
{{#each todo in model}}
    <li>
      <label>{{#link-to "todos.show" list}}{{todo.title}}{{/link-to}}</label>
      <button type="button" class="destroy" {{action "deleteTodo"}}></button>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
```

I put `deleteTodo` action in `toods routes`.
**todos routes** :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
return this.store.find('todo');
 },
deleteTodo: function() {
  // Function itself
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the deleteTodo method into an action on your routes controller instead of on the Route. Then pass your current todo into your controllers deleteTodo method:

```
<button type="button" class="destroy" {{action "deleteTodo" todo}}></button>
```

Looks like your are using ember-cli so the controller would look something like

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    deleteTodo: function(todo){
      todo.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});
```